# I'm definitely giving an integer, but I get Nest::intnm

Tags: plotting, dynamic

I am attempting to make a small interactive plot that displays the plot of `Cos` iterated `its` times. Whenever I try to evaluate my cell, however, I get a `Nest:intnm` error, something like:

```
Nest::intnm: Non-negative machine-sized integer expected at position 3 in Nest[Cos,0.000128356,100].
```

As you can see, the 3rd argument for `Nest` is an integer, but Mathematica is not happy with it. Here is my code:

```
DynamicModule[{its=100},Column[{Plot[Nest[Cos,x,Dynamic[its]],{x,0,2\[Pi]}],Slider[Dynamic[its],{1,500,1}]}]]
```

I've tried changing `Nest[Cos,x,Dynamic[its]]` to `Nest[Cos,x,IntegerPart[Dynamic[its]]]` (so as to catch any sort of glitch where `100` was not seen as an integer) with no avail. This is my first time dealing with anything dynamic, or even sliders, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: `Dynamic[its]` is not an integer. How about `Manipulate[
 Plot[Nest[Cos, x, its], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}], {{its, 1, "its"}, 
  Range[1, 500], ControlType -> Slider}]` ?

Comment: perhaps you want `Dynamic[Plot[...` rather than `Plot[..Dynamic[its]]`?

Comment: @b.gatessucks I tried to account for that possibility by passing it through `IntegerPart` (discussed in my question), but that did not help. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: @b.gatessucks oh sorry, didn't see that last bit. I'll try that.

Comment: @cormullion what is the difference? sorry, I am new at this.

Comment: Ben, I've marked this question as a duplicate as the issue is the same in both cases.  The simplest thing is to move the `Dynamic` outside of `Plot`, but you need to understand what is going on here or you're in for a lot of headache.  Try this: `DynamicModule[{its = 1}, 
 Column[{Dynamic@Plot[Nest[Cos, x, its], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}], 
   Slider[Dynamic[its], {1, 80, 1}]}]]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Vitaliy Kaurov: "...generally the price of dynamic updating is change of Head."

Comment: @Kuba I'm not sure why that commented is directed to me.  Anyway, I think the issue is explained quite well by John Fultz in the post that is linked from my answer to the original question linked above.